# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'

Tags: c#, generics

what I should do here?

On node.Item == target the following error occurs: *Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'*

so I need it all as generic

```
public class Node<T>
    {
       

        public T  Item  { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
        public Node(T item)
        {
                    Item = item;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Item,-15}";
        }
    }

public bool Ancestors(Node<T> node, T target)
{
    if (node == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (node.Item == target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (Ancestors(node.Left, target)
        || Ancestors(node.Right, target))
    {
        Console.Write(node.Item + " ");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: node.Item == target is the place to the error

Comment: Why do you use generic `T` when this code could only ever possibly work with `Node<int>`?

Comment: Presumably you want `T target`, as a `node` can hold anything. To make this work `T`  must be constrained to `IEquatable<T>` in your class declaration.

Comment: Can you post your node t  class, pls

Comment: @Sergey public class Node<T>
    {
       

        public T  Item  { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
        public Node(T item)
        {
                    Item = item;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Item,-15}";
        }
    }

Comment: @Luaan but it's not print the target to

Comment: @JeroenMostert sorry I didn't understand you

Comment: @MusaabK99: Please don't paste code in comments, it's horribly unreadable. Instead, you can edit the question. (Tip: when editing, you don't have to point out that it is an update to the question. Feel free to rewrite the question as if that information was always there, since future readers won't care about it being an update. It's more important that it reads as one cohesive question)

Comment: @Luaan sorry I mean I need the target to be generic too

Comment: @Flater sorry I'm a new here

Comment: @MusaabK99 No worries, we all had to learn it when we were new :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you intend for `target` to have the same generic type as `T` in `Node<T>`. In that case, you should change your method signature to:

```
public bool Ancestors<T>(Node<T> node, T target) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

You would then compare `node.Item` to `target` using:

```
if (node.Item.Equals(target))
```

The complete method could look like this:

```
public bool Ancestors<T>(Node<T> node, T target) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (node?.Item == null)
        return false;

    if (node.Item.Equals(target))
        return true;

    if (Ancestors(node.Left, target) ||
        Ancestors(node.Right, target))
    {
        Console.Write(node.Item + " ");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on this line:

```
if (node.Item == target)
```

In order to compare two items, they must be of the same type (some exceptions apply to this rule, but that's irrelevant for your situation).

So let's confirm that the two things we're comparing are of the same type.

`target` is easy, because your method parameter clearly states `int target`.

So what is `node.Item`? Well, first, let's look at what `node` is in the method declaration:

```
Node<T> node
```

You also posted your `Node<T>` class definition:

```
public class Node<T> 
{ 
    public T Item { get; set; } 
}
```

Therefore, the `Item` property of your `Node<T> node` is of type `T`. But wait, `result` is an `int`. We can't compare that!

Hence the error you're getting:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'

I hope the error makes more sense now.

---

So how do we solve it? Well, *one* of the operands must change type to match the other operand. So we could make both of them `int`:

```
public bool Ancestors(Node<int> node, int target)
{
    if (node.Item == target)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or we can make both operands to be of type `T`:

```
public bool Ancestors(Node<T> node, T target)
{
    if (node.Item.Equals(target))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `Equals` here, instead of `==`, because `==` doesn't work for all types (and the compiler needs to account for all possible types `T` could represent).

The correct solution depends on precisely what you need here.

Comment: when i make it a generic in both side its give me another error *Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'*

Comment: The equality operator cannot be used with a generic type, so your second option will not work.

Comment: @juharr: That's a copy/paste oversight, fixed now.

Comment: @MusaabK99: Yeah I forgot to change it to `Equals`, which does work. Fixed now.